# how to excecute of code written for one microcontroller on another micro controller?

Tags: microcontroller

i have written code for NXP LPC802 micro controller but now i want to test it on lpc824 micro controller. is it possible to run the code. if yes what are the
changes need to do. please suggest me friends..

Comment: Recompile it for the new cpu probably

Comment: Then fix all the bugs caused by differences in compilers.  Then modify all the things that are caused by hardware differences - and fix all the bugs caused by that.  Or ask yourself "Why did I develope this on this one processor when it has to run on this other processor?"

Comment: Separate the code into hardware specific, and hardware independent. Write the independent code in generic C. Write the specific code in C with register references, or assembler if you're masochistic.

Comment: Years ago, I wrote code for some image processing. Most of it in C, only very small but frequently used inner loops in assembler. The speed up was amazing. Mixing of C with assembler was possible, no need to write assembler subroutines callable from C.

Comment: Hey folks, try paying attention to the act that these are similar part numbers from the same vendor.  Both are Cortex-M0+ cores with probably only slightly differing memories and peripherals.  This is far simpler and more practical than the *general* form of the question.  In these types of situations sometimes one doesn't even have to change anything at all.  And sometimes vendors write migration guides that specifically compare parts of their product line.

Comment: There are of course critical issues with the *statement* of question that make it not fit here, but the *technical task* is nowhere near what the off target comments posted above erroneously suggest it is.

Comment: @ChrisStratton In this case, it makes me even sader, that op cannot figure this out himself

Answer (score 2):

> how to excecute of code written for one microcontroller on another micro controller?

- You don't at the binary level.

  You don't if the source is in assembler.

If the source is in a standard high level language, like C for example, then it should be possible, but usually requires some work.  C is poorly suited for the unusual memory architecture of many microcontrollers, so the language ends up being extended in proprietary ways for each platform.  There are also differences in what the default integer size is, etc.

It is possible to write code up front that mitigates most of these problems, but now is too late to think about that.

Either way, there is no substitute for reading the compiler manual for the original system, reading the compiler manual for the new system, carefully noting differences, then going over the code to update it to those differences.  How much work this is depends on how well the code was written in the first place.

### Added

I answered the general case above.  I just noticed that you are trying to port code between two similar processors.  I don't know the NXP line, and you have provide no information on these two micros, but at least they are from the same manufacturer.  That means the proprietary extensions to the high level language will likely be similar, if not identical, between the two processors.  If both use the same compiler, then there shouldn't be much of a language issue.

Any porting tasks then come down to changing the low level code to account for the hardware difference.  This should be easy if the hardware is similar and the code was written properly in the first place.  Look at the datasheets of the two processor, see what is different about the peripherals and other hardware, figure out which ones you are actually using, then make the changes.  If the code was written properly, this could be as easy as changing a few configuration constants.

Comment: I think that might have been true 20 years ago, but it has since come a long way. I've never seen non-c syntaxe in most of the codes of the micro controllers I'm working with, sometimes, very rarely, a few assembly lines for critical sections but that is very rare. With the increase in complexity of the program, I do not believe it makes any sense to write programs in assembly anymore. The compilers are now able to greatly optimize the code and the cost of maintaining an assembly code worth to have a few cent more expensive chip.

Comment: @Dam: There are still a lot of proprietary pragma statements used to extend the C language to details of particular architectures.

Comment: It is true, but in the last 8 years doing mostly embedded programming, I think I've had to use it once for some special extended 16bit memory access, or sometimes interrupt config

Answer (score 2):

If the code is in assembly, it will be a long task.

If it is, very likely, written in C, Most of the applicative code shall works fine as is.

Where you will get problems is on the hardware level in both the board and chip peripherals.

That is why good practices is to always keep the applicative code and  hardware related code, often called drivers, separated, as well as the board hardware mapping (which pin is connected to what) usually called hardware profile.

Depending on your code, you should evaluate how complex it would be, if the drivers and hardware level peripherals (timers, spi, interrupts, etc...) are well separated, it shouldn't be hard, you will probably need to rewrite or find some of the drivers according to your new chip.

If it's all mixed up, it might become very complex and painstaking.